# Azure App Service with Internal Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

Scenario:

- Virtual Network has 3 Subnets for APIM (subnetAPIM, `10.0.1.0/24`), Virtual Machines (subnetVM `10.0.8.0/24`), Gateway (subnetGateway `10.0.2.0/24`)
- API Management Virtual Network Mode is set to **Internal** and APIM is placed in a subnet dedicated to APIM. So APIM is not accessible
  publicly. The internal IP assigned is **10.0.5.1**
- Virtual Machine is placed in subnetVM (`10.0.8.0/24`) and is able to invoke APIs (in APIM) successfully using hostname. I had to update host file on Virtual Machine.
- App Service is also in same Virtual Network (with P2S Gateway, Address space `122.1.0.0/24`)
- App Service settings show that IP address `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255` will be routed to VNET

Issue:

- App Service (in VNET) is not able to reach `https://10.0.1.5/echo/resource`. The HTTP error code is `ServiceUnavailable`
- App Service (in VNET) is not able to resolve `customdomain.azure-api.net` when it tries to reach `https://customdomain.azure-api.net/echo/resource`

Any additional configuration required to make this work?

Comment: Issue #1 We dont respond on IP Address

Comment: Issue #2 AppService does not know, about customdomain.azure-api.net inside the VNET. You need to setup Custom DNS server in the VNET and have a mapping for customdomain.azure-api.net to 10.0.1.5. When AppService will try to a dns lookup for customdomain, that will succeed and APIM will respond appropriately.

Comment: @Samir wouldn't App Service use Azure DNS to resolve APIM proxy address `custom.azure-api.net`?

Comment: Azure DNS is only for resolving public hostname to public IP address. Inside the VNET APIM proxy is hosted on private IP address range as defined RFC1918.